# Can't connect to mongo in Docker

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker, mongoose

I'm practicing Docker with a dummy app but I can't connect with the database. If anyone can give a clue about what the problem could be, please. Thanks in advance for any help. If any more info is needed please let me know.

Here is my Dockerfile for api:

**Dockerfile in server**

```
FROM node:14-alpine

WORKDIR usr/app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .

EXPOSE 3400

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

**Here is my connection to db in db.js**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const uri = 'mongodb://mongo:27017/prueba-docker';
const connect = async () => {
  try {
    await mongoose.connect(uri, {});
    console.log('conected to db');
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('error connecting to db', err);
  }
};
module.exports = { connect };
```

**And here docker-compose**

```
version: "3"
services:
  prueba-react:
    image: prueba-react
    build: ./client/
    stdin_open: true
    ports: 
      - "3000:3000"
    networks: 
      - mern-app
  
  prueba-api:
    image: prueba-api
    build: ./server/
    ports: 
      - "3400:3400"
    networks:
      - mern-app
    depends_on:
      - db
  db:
    image: mongo:4.4-bionic
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    networks:
      - mern-app
    volumes:
      - mongo-data:/data/db

networks:
  mern-app:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  mongo-data:
    driver: local
```

First I found out that I should  stop mongo wiht the command because I had a port conflict.

```
sudo systemctl stop mongod
```

But now I don't understand why It gives an error when I do docker-compose up

This is the error I get

```
prueba-api_1    | error connecting to db MongooseServerSelectionError: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN mongo
prueba-api_1    |     at NativeConnection.Connection.openUri (/usr/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:796:32)
prueba-api_1    |     at /usr/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:328:10
prueba-api_1    |     at /usr/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/helpers/promiseOrCallback.js:32:5
prueba-api_1    |     at new Promise (<anonymous>)
prueba-api_1    |     at promiseOrCallback (/usr/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/helpers/promiseOrCallback.js:31:10)
prueba-api_1    |     at Mongoose._promiseOrCallback (/usr/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:1149:10)
prueba-api_1    |     at Mongoose.connect (/usr/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:327:20)
prueba-api_1    |     at Object.connect (/usr/app/db.js:6:20)
prueba-api_1    |     at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/app/app.js:6:4)
prueba-api_1    |     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1072:14) {
prueba-api_1    |   reason: TopologyDescription {
prueba-api_1    |     type: 'Unknown',
prueba-api_1    |     servers: Map(1) { 'mongo:27017' => [ServerDescription] },
prueba-api_1    |     stale: false,
prueba-api_1    |     compatible: true,
prueba-api_1    |     heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
prueba-api_1    |     localThresholdMS: 15,
prueba-api_1    |     logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: undefined
prueba-api_1    |   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `docker-compose.yml` you are creating a `network` called `mern-app` where all `services` are assigned to that `network`. To communicate between `containers` in a `docker network` all you have to do is use the `service` name. Instead of `mongodb://mongo:27017/prueba-docker` try connecting to `mongodb://db:27017/prueba-docker`.

You also mentioned a port conflict. It seems like you are already running `mongodb`. If you don't want to stop your `mongodb` everytime you want to try out your `docker-compose`, you could just map to another port:

```
    ports:
      - "27018:27017"
```

Or you could just don't expose your `mongodb` at all if no external `application` is using your `db`. This only introduces `security threats`.

Comment: Thank you very much, It worked perfecto. I didint realize that It was such a silly mistake. Cheers!!